# How return `A**n` in python with A an matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

I'm using sympy. For any matrix `A` I want the form of `A**n` but when I write

```
>>> from __future__ import division

>>> from sympy import *

>>> import sympy

>>> from sympy.abc import *

>>> import sys

>>> sys.displayhook = pprint

>>> from sympy.matrices import *

>>> A = Matrix([[a, b], [c, d]])

>>> A**n
```

I get

```
>>> Only integer and rational values are supported
```

and I hope the matrix form of `A**n`.

Comment: Do you want to multiply the matrix with itself? Or square each element of the matrix?

Comment: You should post a minimal working example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If put a number I get that I want, but really I hope a symbolic form. So I want put `n`. I add all the code am using so you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

The power of a matrix by a symbolic variable is not implemented yet, the error *NotImplementedError* is quite clear in that regard, however you may try this code:

```
def jordan_cell_power(jc, n):
        N = jc.shape[0]
        l = jc[0, 0]
        for i in range(N):
                for j in range(N-i):
                        bn = binomial(n, i)
                        if isinstance(bn, binomial):
                                bn = bn._eval_expand_func()
                        jc[j, i+j] = l**(n-i)*bn


def matrix_power(M, n):
        P, jordan_cells = M.jordan_cells()
        for j in jordan_cells:
                jordan_cell_power(j, n)
        return P*diag(*jordan_cells)*P.inv()
```

This is the implementation given on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers

That is, a matrix is reduced to the jordan form, that is, you find two matrices *P* and *J* for which *A == P*J*P.inv()*, such that *J* in represented in the Jordan normal form.

At this point, each Jordan cell is evaluated its power through some simple combinatorics (following the instruction on Wikipedia's article about calculating the power of a matrix in Jordan normal form).

Given that *A**n == P*J*P*P.inv()*J* ... *J*P.inv() == P*J**n*P.inv()*, there's an easy way to convert it back.

You can try this with your examples:

```
In [3]: A = Matrix([[1, a], [0, 1]])

In [4]: A 
Out[4]: 
[1  a]
[    ]
[0  1]

In [5]: matrix_power(A, n)
Out[5]:
[1  a*n]
[      ]
[0   1 ]

In [6]: B = Matrix([[a, b], [c, d]])

In [7]: matrix_power(B, n)
... enormous result ...
```

Comment: This help me, now I havent problem. Thanks

Comment: By the way, I proposed this code to be added to SymPy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/9986
If accepted, next SymPy version will have a working A**n